# NSPredicate and filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate problem

Tags: objective-c

```
for (int i = 0; i < nCount1; i ++) {
        CGatewayMedia * media = (CGatewayMedia *)[GatewayDetail.mcMutableArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSString * zStr1 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",media.mnSNO];
        NSString * zStr2 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",media.mcstrMOrgName];
        NSString * zStr3 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",media.mcstrUser];
        NSString * zStr4 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",media.mcstrFType];
        NSString * zStr5 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",media.mcstrFSize];
        NSString * zStr6 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",media.mcstrFDate];
        NSString * zStr7 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",media.mnMedID];
        NSString * zStr8 = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",media.mcstrMedSysName];
        CGatewayData * zDataObject = [[CGatewayData alloc]initWithString1:zStr1 
                                                               andString2:zStr2 
                                                               andString3:zStr3
                                                               andString4:zStr4
                                                               andString5:zStr5
                                                               andString6:zStr6
                                                               andString7:zStr7
                                                               andString8:zStr8
                                      ];


        [mMedia.nsMutaryOfDataObject addObject:zDataObject];
    } 
    mMedia->mcMediaController->nsMutaryOfDataObject = nil;
    mMedia->mcMediaController->nsMutaryOfDataObject = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate
                              predicateWithFormat:@"(zDataObject.nsStrName4 == %@) OR (zDataObject.nsStrName4 == %@ )",@"MP3",@"WMA"];*/
    mMedia->mcMediaController->nsMutaryOfDataObject = (NSMutableArray*)[mMedia.nsMutaryOfDataObject filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

i'm not getting expected result ..m i doing right use of prediacte and filteredArrayUsingPredicate?

Comment: `mMedia->mcMediaController->nsMutaryOfDataObject = nil;`?  */me vomits*

Comment: surprised? actually it works in Objective-C when you declare your member vars as @public. Because object's are handled as c structs.
But yeah, you should never ever do that!!!

Comment: @V1ru8 yes i know it works, but (as you say) you should never ever do that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `zStr` strings are leaking. You init them with `alloc] init...]` so they have a retain count of +1. After adding them to your CGatewayData object you should release them. And of corse your CGatewayData object should retain them as long as it needs them. Same thing with your `zDataObject`.
Take a look at the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html)

Second do never nuse -> in Objective-C! You should use properties for that!

Now to your problem. You have to be sure that the path `zDataObject.nsStrName4` exists. Means the object accessed by `mMedia.nsMutaryOfDataObject` in your code. Should have at least a getter called `zDataObject` and I assume it returns a `CGatewayData` object. So the `CGatewayData` object has to have at least a getter called `nsStrName4`. 
For details I highly recommend to read the [Key-Value Coding Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i)